# Javascript for showing a div using the div's class name

Tags: javascript

I have a div in my page like that,

```
  <div class="errormsg" style="display: none;">Username is empty</div>
```

i am having an input field like this,

```
  <input type=textbox id="userid" />
```

Now i need a javascript for showing the error message div if input field was empty. I need to use the div class rather than id. Please help.

P.S : I don't want Jquery as my page has some restriction to use library files.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: Couple different options explored by John Resig: http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,  assuming only one `errormsg` div -

**Update**
I've added a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8jdNm/5/). Plus, there was a typo - corrected

```
<div class="errormsg" style="display: none;">Username is empty</div>
<input type=textbox id="userid" onchange="validate()" />

function validate(){
    var userId = document.getElementById('userId'),
        errorMsg = document.getElementsByClassName('errormsg').item();
    if (userId.value === ''){
       errorMsg.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
       errorMsg.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: wait, let me make a fiddle for you

Comment: It's set to go `onchange` - so you have to press enter to update the values

Comment: Can u please help me with on click example? In my page the function is not proceeding after getElementsByClassName line. I am not getting any alert too... Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="errormsg">Username is empty</div>
<input type='textbox' id="userid" onkeyup="javascript:call(this);" />

function getElementsByClassName(className) {
    // For IE    
    if (document.all) {
        var allElements = document.all;
    } else {
        var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    }   
    var foundElements = [];  

    for (var i = 0, ii = allElements.length; i < ii; i++) {
        if (allElements[i].className == className) {
            foundElements[foundElements.length] = allElements[i];
        }
    }

    return foundElements;

}

function call(control)
{
    var userid=document.getElementById('userid');
    var errorMsg = getElementsByClassName('errormsg')[0];
    if(userid.value == '')
    {        
        errorMsg.style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        errorMsg.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Removed the JQuery and added the Javascript code as below:

```
<div class="errormsg">Username is empty</div>
<input type='textbox' id="userid" onkeyup="javascript:call(this);" />

function getElementsByClassName(className) {
    // For IE    
    if (document.all) {
        var allElements = document.all;
    } else {
        var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    }   
    var foundElements = [];  

    for (var i = 0, ii = allElements.length; i < ii; i++) {
        if (allElements[i].className == className) {
            foundElements[foundElements.length] = allElements[i];
        }
    }

    return foundElements;

}

function call(control)
{
    var userid=document.getElementById('userid');
    var errorMsg = getElementsByClassName('errormsg')[0];
    if(userid.value == '')
    {        
        errorMsg.style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
        errorMsg.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u please suggest me how we can check this with javascript? I am having some restrictions on using library files.